# SQL Distinct based on two columns Order By count

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
-------------------------
|  ID | Make  | Model   |
|   1 | Ford  | Cortina |
|   2 | Ford  | Escort  |
|   3 | Ford  | Cortina |
|   4 | VW    | Golf    |
|   5 | Audi  | Quattro |
|   6 | Ford  | Cortina |
|   7 | VW    | Golf    |
|   8 | Ford  | Escort  |
|   9 | Fiat  | Uno     |
|  10 | Honda | Civic   |
-------------------------
```

I want to be able to SELECT the TOP 5 rows based on DISTINCT Make & Model with a count so the result looks like this:-

```
----------------------------
|  Count | Make  | Model   |
|      3 | Ford  | Cortina |
|      2 | Ford  | Escort  |
|      1 | Ford  | Cortina |
|      1 | VW    | Golf    |
|      1 | Audi  | Quattro |
----------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this query:

```
SELECT TOP 5 COUNT(ID) as COUNT, MAKE, MODEL
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY MAKE, MODEL
ORDER BY COUNT(ID) DESC, MAKE
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14cb9/3)